# Is it possible to change your single-player skin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In *Minecraft*, is it possible to customize your skin in single-player mode (not just in multiplayer)? How?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you change your skin, it affects both single player and multi-player.

If you don't see your skin in single player, make sure you're online so it can download the skin.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible.  Multi-player and single-player modes use the same skin.  Create or download your skin, then upload it by logging into minecraft.net, and selecting the Profile link.

Since there's no reflective surfaces in Minecraft, the only way to see your skin in single player is to go to third person view by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> (and again to switch back to first person view) or simply opening the inventory.

Comment: Also you can see it on your arm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You download the skin you want then go to the profile page on Minecraft.net and it should say what to do.