# How do I change Minecraft skin in multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change your single-player skin?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18192/is-it-possible-to-change-your-single-player-skin)

I changed my skin in my single player Minecraft, but when I play multiplayer on servers, my skin is just plain old stievie! How can I make my skin look different (On Man) and visible even on Minecraft servers? I don't own a premium account.

Comment: Protip: Buy Minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your [Minecraft Profile](http://minecraft.net/profile); login to change your skin.

[image]

But if you don't have a premium account you won't be able to change the skin and you won't get any further help because you officially can't play on servers without a premium account.